# What is wrong with this js function that resend activation email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a function to resend the activation email.

When user try to login and user is not activated then a message show up with a link (you can see below).

It doesn't work at all. Can't even reach the js function if i'm correct.

What can be the problem? Please help me out.

Link that call the function:

```
<a href="#" email="'.$this->input->post('email').'" id="resend_activation">Aktiváló e-mail újraküldése</a>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#resend_activation', function()
{

    var email = $(this).attr('email');  
    $("#success_msgforword").hide();
    $(".errors").hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: base_url + "aktivalo-ujrakuldes?email="+email,
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(data)
        { 
            if(data==0)
            {
                $(".errors").html('Error! You are logged in!').show();
            }
            else if(data==1)
            {
                $(".errors").html('');
                $(".success_msgforword").html('Success, you wil receive an email from us shortly.').show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller that puts the caller link:

```
        if (isset($errors['user_banned'])) {    /* banned user */
            $this->_show_message('error', $this->lang->line('auth_message_banned').' <br/><br/>Indok: '.$errors['user_banned']);
        } elseif (isset($errors['not_activated'])) {    /* not activated user */
            $test = 'A felhasználói fiók nincs aktiválva! <br/><a href="#" email="'.$this->input->post('email').'" id="resend_activation">Aktiváló e-mail újraküldése</a>';
            $json = array(
                'errors' => $test
            );
        } else {    /*  fail */
            foreach ($errors as $k => $v){ $test = $this->lang->line($v);}
            $json = array(
                'errors' => $test
            );
        }
```

Comment: If I put the link that calls function without later showing up as error, then it works.

Comment: Be a lot more specific about what is and what isn't working. Also note any errors that may be thrown and inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what status and response body look like

Comment: Can you show us your server side code? And your html.

Comment: Added the relevant part of my controller. If user not activated then show link, also check if user is banned, then show the relevant message to the <div class="errors"></div>

Comment: Can you add an error part to your ajax? And log possible errors?